# I got the same message twice

Tags: c#, facebook, bots, botframework

I used this code to send a different message if a new user start conversation :

```
IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;
            var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
            if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
            {
                foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
                {
                    if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        var reply = message.CreateReply();
                        reply.Text = $"Welcome {newMember.Name}! You are a new member! If you want to see help menu , type : help";
                        client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
```

My problem is that when a user click in facebook : Get started  this message comes twice.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Is there more than 1 newMember in update.MembersAdded?

Comment: i don't know ? do you have any idea how to resolve ?

Comment: Can you breakpoint on the foreach line and step through the code. I am not sure what the issue is exactly but that would be a good place to start looking. Any more details can help get you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook includes the conversation itself in the list of members:

[image]

So you need to change the `if` statement to this:

```
if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id && newMember.Id != message.Conversation.Id)
{ 
   // send welcome message
```

Comment: The code is inaccurate; the post you are linking just mention that you need to add the if for checking the recipient; you don't need to check the conversation.Id and also the post is from the emulator and he is talking about facebook

Comment: @stuartd with this you mean also i can catch the username of person also ?  It is possible to said welcome {username} of person

Comment: @user2454923 `message.From.Name` should give you the name, though I haven't tested that in this specific scenario.

Comment: When i test this in Facebook i got the message without the user name :( Can you me please how to catch the username ? Also if you can , i want to reset user data also ...to let the user to reset the bot , restart it. Thnx in advace

Comment: @stuartd in Emulator i got message : Welcome User

Comment: Possibly FB doesn't send the user name with a conversationUpdate, I'm not set up to test that right now though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the facebook Name part...
You should be able to just plug in this code:

```
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            IConversationUpdateActivity iConversationUpdated = message as IConversationUpdateActivity;
            if (iConversationUpdated != null)
            {
                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                foreach (var member in iConversationUpdated.MembersAdded ?? System.Array.Empty<ChannelAccount>())
                {
                    // if the bot is added, then
                    if (member.Id == iConversationUpdated.Recipient.Id)
                    {

                        var reply = ((Activity)iConversationUpdated).CreateReply($"Hi Friend I'm Botty McBotface");
                        connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```