# Welcome/Initial Message sent twice

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework, skype, chatbot

I have the following code that sends a message whenever a user connects to the bot:

```
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels

            IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;
            var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
            if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
            {
                foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
                {
                    if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        var reply = message.CreateReply("Welcome to the ChatBot! Say a 'Hello'");
                        client.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code works fine on the Emulator. But when it comes to Skype and Facebook, the message is shown twice.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at TopicName, maybe it differes in both cases.

Comment: For Facebook, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433326/i-got-the-same-message-twice/44433818#44433818)

Comment: @Quantic because the recipient - the bot - is also in the conversation.

Comment: Change  **if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id)** to **if (member.Id == update.Recipient.Id)**